# Change a cookie via JavasScript without changing expiry date

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to set the value of an existing cookie without changing the expiry date. Example:

`document.cookie="username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 GMT; path=/";`

to

`document.cookie="username=David Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 GMT; path=/";`

It's important to use only JavaScript.

Thanks.

Comment: Cookies are stored as key-value pairs and as far as I know you cannot read the expire date of a cookie and re-use it to set it when overwriting a cookie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way I know of to achieve such a task is to save the original expiration date as part of the cookie data, then reuse it each time you set an existing cookie.

```
function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue){
    var expireDate = document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName) === -1
            ? new Date(new Date().setTime(new Date().getTime()+30*24*60*60*1000)) // 30 days
            : unescape(document.cookie).split('expireDate=')[1]; // split out date to reuse
    document.cookie = cookieName + '=' + cookieValue + ',expireDate=' + expireDate + ';expires=' + expireDate;
}
```

Taken and refactored from [here](http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-programming/67081-update-cookie-value-without-changing-its-expire-date.html).

Comment: I'm using your method, but in the expiry date it says "Session".

Comment: OK, it was because I was creating a cookie with my method, and then setting the value with your metohd. It seems the cookie became crazy.

Comment: The method uses nothing out of the ordinary so it should work properly on all major browsers, including very old ones (e.g. IE6)

Comment: this answer is incomplete, it misses the getCookieValue function call, to read out the cookie value without expiration date

Comment: @Toskan op didn't ask for a full implamantation of cookies management but a way to set cookies. Feel free to add your own answer if you find this one lacking, the more the merrier